# Monodroid and pushsharp

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.android

Has anyone implemented push notifications in their monodroid application using Push Sharp (https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp)?

I would like to use this solution but I have't been able to run a test yet.

Can anyone put up a tutorial on how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @SpiritMachine : thanks for the link!! I will probably have occasions to provide it...

Answer (score 8):

I'm the author of PushSharp.

GCM is working quite well, and is pretty easy to get up and running!

To setup your Google API's project, you can follow this guide:
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-GCM-Google-Cloud-Messaging-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp

As @SpiritMachine mentioned, you can use the Client Sample for your Mono For Android application.  It may be easiest (as mentioned) to simply take the project, and tweak it to your liking.
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/tree/master/Client.Samples/PushSharp.ClientSample.MonoForAndroid/PushSharp.ClientSample.MonoForAndroid.Gcm

Finally, sending GCM notifications using PushSharp from your server is quite trivial:

```
//Create a new instance of PushService
PushService push = new PushService();

//Configure and start Android GCM
//IMPORTANT: The SENDER_ID is your Google API Console App Project ID.
//  Be sure to get the right Project ID from your Google APIs Console.  
//  It's not the named project ID that appears in the Overview,
//  but instead the numeric project id in the url: 
//    eg: https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:785671162406:overview
//  where 785671162406 is the project id, which is the SENDER_ID to use!
push.StartGoogleCloudMessagingPushService(
  new GcmPushChannelSettings("785671162406", "AIzaSyC2PZNXQDVaUpZGmtsF_Vp8tHtIABVjazI", "com.pushsharp.test"));

//Fluent construction of an Android GCM Notification
//IMPORTANT: For Android you MUST use your own RegistrationId here 
//  that gets generated within your Android app itself!
push.QueueNotification(NotificationFactory.AndroidGcm()
    .ForDeviceRegistrationId("<YOUR_REGISTRATION_ID_HERE>")
    .WithCollapseKey("NONE")
    .WithJson("{\"alert\":\"Alert Text!\",\"badge\":\"7\"}"));

//Stop the server if you have nothing else to send for a long time
// and tell it to process the remaining queue before exiting!
push.StopAllServices(true);
```

Naturally, PushSharp is available on NuGet as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've managed to make it run. Very clean and easy to use. Great solution :)

Comment: If you're looking for the "Application ID Package Name" of an already published app (I was asked to modify one), go to the Play Store's app's page and it'll be in the URL (ID=...)

Answer (score 1):

GCM definitely works well on Android.

The PushSharp server application looks like it provides some quite nice features and management across multiple mobile OS implementations.

However, if you're really looking just to access the GCM API with a more minimal functionality, you can get up and running fairly quickly.

I wrote my own bare bones server in Ruby using [this gem](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm). It's a Sinatra application that just allows devices to register/unregister and provides HTTP URL to post messages. I did it in about 30 LOC. No joke. It's running on Heroku.

Then I just took the MonoDroid client example from the PushSharp repository, customised it to register/unregister with my API and otherwise gave it a nip and tuck to suit my needs.

First thing though, you'll need to create a project with Google APIs and turn on GCM for it. You can start with that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I've got the Push Sharp project up and running. I will also need support to iPhone push notifications so I think I'm gonna go the Push Sharp way